# Checking if a Data Binding Exists

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I am dynamically loading a xaml file into my program that has a binding:

```
<ListView
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Grid.Row="2" BorderBrush="White" Name="ListView1"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=line}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Lines"
             DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=aline}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView >
```

In my program, I want to check if the Binding exists.

How should this be achieved?

**Edit:** The `aline` is a property of the `DataContext` object

Comment: Can I ask why you want to check this? Or what "problem" you're trying to solve? There might be a better way.

Comment: I basically need the loaded xaml to always have a binding, if not then I need to add a binding. Eventually, I will not know the content of the xaml being loaded in.

Answer (score 13):

You can check for bindings like this:

```
BindingExpression be = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(ListView1, ItemsSourceProperty);
return be != null ? "ItemsSource is bound" : "ItemsSource is not bound";
```

Comment: I've never seen a return statement like this before. I believe I do not understand some of the syntax, can you explain briefly what this will actually return (boolean, string)?

Comment: This is only an example. Here it will return a string for demonstration but of course you can customize it for your needs.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ty67wk28.aspx for shorthand syntax details.

Comment: This will only show that there is Binding statement on the ListView1's ItemSource.  I believe the question was not completely clear and as mentioned below @david actually wants to prove that not only does the statement exist but that it is bound to something.  This should be edited to include a && be.ResolvedSource!=null.

Comment: @justinarsine: I'm not convinced. [BindingExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpression.aspx) is a concrete instance of a [Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.aspx) statement. From [GetBindingExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.getbindingexpression.aspx) remarks: "Checking the return value for null is a technique you can use to determine whether a property has an active binding.". If I'm wrong it should be no problem to add further checks as you suggested.

Comment: @LPL: I created a little program to verify that a {Binding something} will produce a non null return value even though the something property does not exist in the DataContext.    This method will return a valid value if the Dependency property is available/attempting to connect to a property in the DataContext.

Answer (score -3):

```
if (ListView1.ItemsSource != null)
            Console.WriteLine("Is Bound");
        else Console.WriteLine("Is Not bound");
```

Comment: This will only check whether ItemsSource has a value not if this value is a binding. I can assign `"123"` to ItemsSource and it will show 3 Items but it is not a binding.

Comment: I would agree but the code above shows ItemsSource="{Binding Path=line}".  So if 'line' doesn't existin the datacontext then there is no binding.

Comment: @justinarsine: that is not true. Consider the case where the `DataContext` changes to an object with a `lines` property. The binding will then work. Why? Because the Binding was always there.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: well now you have me thinking.  If there is a binding statement in the xaml but no corresponding DataContext Property, is there a binding?  There is one side but not the other.  My first thought under your scenario is that no binding exists initially and then when a new DataContext is added with a corresponding property then a binding does exist.

Comment: @sixlettervariables is correct. The `DataContext` is an object with the `aline` property. Sorry for the confusion, I will update my question.

Comment: @David: Ok. I think I have some confusion about if you are verifying that there is a binding statement in the xaml vs if you are verifying that the binding statement in the xaml is actually bound to a property in the datacontext.

Comment: @justinarsine preferably both, but wouldn't checking if the binding statement in the xaml is actually bound to a property in the `DataContext` infer that a binding statement exists in the xaml? If so, then I would like to verify that the binding statement in the xaml is actually bound to a property in the `DataContext`

Comment: @David: I agree that checking that the binding statement in the xaml is actually bound to a property would prove that the statement exists in xaml and is bound to a property in the datacontext.  But using the GetBindingExpression() as it is stated in the above answer will only provide you with the knowledge that there is a {Binding line} statement in xaml.

Comment: @David: Further information must be checked to show that it is bound to a property in your datacontext.  You can 1) use my statement shows a value is set for ItemsSource or 2) use the GetBindingExpression() from above and verify the "ReslovedSource" property is not null. Would be something like be.ResolvedSource!=null.